# Sharper Bound for Minkowski's Convex Body Theorem

Tags: geometry, number-theory

To satisfy the conditions of Minkowski's Convex Body Theorem we need a lattice $\Lambda$ with fundamental domain $T$ and a bounded convex symmetric subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (call it $X$) with $vol(X)>2^nvol(T)$ (this guarantees that a non-zero point of $\Lambda$ lies in $X$). Are there any conditions we could impose on $X$ in order to obtain a smaller bound than $2^nvol(T)$? (I'm especially concerned with the $n=3$ case).

Comment: No, the bound is sharp for a cube (for example). Unless you know more than just convexity you cannot beat the bound from Minkowski.

Comment: You might be able to get a sharper bound for a particular region and a particular lattice, but that bound would depend on the details of your lattice and region. Can you specify any further what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to work with an ellipsoid in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the standard integer lattice ($\mathbb{Z}^3$)

Comment: Is your ellipsoid oriented parallel to the coordinate axes, or are we talking about a generic ellipsoid in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: It is oriented parallel to the coordinate axes and it is defined by $2x^2+y^2+z^2<m$